# How to assign mapState list of data?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js, apexcharts

Currently, I am working on apex bar chart, wanted to assign list of `mapState` data into apex series data.

Below is the code:

```
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
export default {
  data: () => ({
    series: [{
              name: 'Completed',
              data: [44, 55, 57, 58, 56, 61, 58, 63, 60, 66, 67, 62]
            }, {
              name: 'Total',
              data: [100, 90, 101, 100, 98, 87, 105, 97, 114, 94, 112, 100]
          }]
    }),
computed: {
      ...mapState(['userAssignmentProgessTotal','userAssignmentProgessCompleted']),
    },
}
</script>
```

```
mapState value:
userAssignmentProgessTotal: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
userAssignmentProgessCompleted: [45, 29, 32, 17, 1, 13, 12, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

And I wanted to assign like below:

```
series: [{
              name: 'Completed',
              data: this.userAssignmentProgessTotal
            }, {
              name: 'Total',
              data: this.userAssignmentProgessCompleted
          }]
```

but getting error as:

```
Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'userAssignmentProgessTotal' of undefined"
```

I am very new to vuex as well as vuejs. Apologies if I haven't described well. Thanks

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: pls post the exact error you are getting

Comment: also, where are you assigning this, do you some have a method where you are assigning this? or on mounted ? or you want it reactive ?

Comment: I have no idea how to assign that. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Sure, have tried answering for both the cases if you want it `reactive` or `manual update` data property

Comment: I've used your 1st approach, getting the same error. `Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'userAssignmentProgessTotal' of undefined"`

Comment: And in the 2nd approach, there is no error but the bar chart isn't showing.

Comment: have you removed `series` from `data` property & made a `computed` property by that name as in 1st approach.

Comment: Also, if you are setting your data property in `mounted` you need to call the respective `dispatch` before setting the data so that getter are populated as per API responses.

Comment: Now in the first approach, value is changing on the x-axis.

Comment: Great, so if you think the solution helped you & resolved your query pls upvote & accept the answer so that it can help others as well. Thanks

Comment: @ShivamSingh the value should change with proportion to the y-axis. I will share the screenshot. Please refer the above screenshot

Comment: that's not related to your question, there may be some other issue at the component level data or in the way you are assigning values to the graph, pls ask your further query in another question with the relevant tag so that the community expert related to that stack can help you out better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [1] If you want the `series` to be reactive ie. keep changing / updating when
>   `userAssignmentProgessTotal` or `userAssignmentProgessCompleted`
>   changes, make series a `computed` property instead of `data` property

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {  
    ...mapState([
      'userAssignmentProgessTotal',
      'userAssignmentProgessCompleted'
    ]),
    series () {
      return [{
        name: 'Completed',
        // If `userAssignmentProgessTotal` is any falsy value it will return the default array else will return `userAssignmentProgessTotal`
        data: this.userAssignmentProgessTotal || [44, 55, 57, 58, 56, 61, 58, 63, 60, 66, 67, 62]
      }, {
        name: 'Total',
        data: this.userAssignmentProgessCompleted || [100, 90, 101, 100, 98, 87, 105, 97, 114, 94, 112, 100]
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

> [2] If you want to manually update `series`, make a `method` to update
>   `series`

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      series () {
        return [{
          name: 'Completed',
          data: [44, 55, 57, 58, 56, 61, 58, 63, 60, 66, 67, 62]
        }, {
          name: 'Total',
          data: [100, 90, 101, 100, 98, 87, 105, 97, 114, 94, 112, 100]
        }]
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'userAssignmentProgessTotal',
      'userAssignmentProgessCompleted'
    ])
  },

  methods: {
    updateSeries () {
      this.$set(this.series, 0, { name: this.series[0].name, data: this.userAssignmentProgessTotal })
      this.$set(this.series, 1, { name: this.series[1].name, data: this.userAssignmentProgessCompleted })
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    // call dispatches to fetch data
    // ...
    // call the method in mounted to update series when component loads 
    // or else whenever you want to update series
    this.updateSeries()  
  }
}
```